# Are EPP status codes case-sensitive?

Tags: case-sensitive, rfc, whois, epp

When I reviewed [the relevant RFC documents](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/std69), I couldn't find anything about the case sensitivity of [the status codes](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en). Therefore, I wanted to ask this question here.

I have encountered the following EPP codes, but I don't know whether they are valid. Additionally, I don't know whether these codes are considered by an automation process or if they are just for the registrant information.

Let me simplify my question; Are EPP status codes case-sensitive, and are they just for the registrant's information?

**Example 1 - with a link**

```
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
```

**Example 2 - lower cases**

```
Domain Status: clienttransferprohibited
Domain Status: clientupdateprohibited
Domain Status: clientrenewprohibited
Domain Status: clientdeleteprohibited
```

**Example 3 - normal**

```
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientRenewProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the XML-Schema definitions attached to the RFC, you will see that these status codes are defined as case-sensitive. Also some of the ICANN publications like [this](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en) are referencing them case-sensitive.

But:

- EPP Server implementations may differ on RFC implementation
- Confusing other guidelines on how to display status codes exsist (as for WHOIS eg only `Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok` would pass any ICANN conformance test)

So it is save to assume that normalized status codes would always match ;-)

So the answer to `Are EPP status codes case-sensitive?` is **Yes**